# Visualforce nested pageblocksections collapse all space

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex

I am trying nested pageblocksections in visualforce apex page. I want the sections to be collapsed by default. I searched on line and found a javascript code to colllapse the sections by default. But when I put some text in the sections it appears in the middle. This code is adding unnecessary space in front of the text. My code is

```
<apex:page  >
   <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 1" id="op1">
          <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.op1}')); 
                </script>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <span>This is a test</span>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 2" id="op2">
        <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.op2}')); 
                </script>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <span>This is a test</span>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 3" id="op3">
           <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.op3}')); 
                </script>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <span>This is a test</span>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    
</apex:page>
```

the result is

[image]

How to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong but it has nothing to do with "twistSection".

When you use [`pageBlockSectionItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) you "promise" there will be 2 tags inside it and SF will put them as columns in the table. First will be used as "field label", second will be "field value". If there's just 1 tag - your content will be centered in the space where the 2 columns should be. Between this and the default being 2-column layout inside [`pageBlockSection`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm) - stuff looks centered.

See if this gives you better ideas

```html
<apex:page >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 1" id="op1">
            <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.op1}')); </script>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <span>This is a test</span>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 2" id="op2" columns="1">
            <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.op2}')); </script>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Label here</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputText >Payload here</apex:outputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 3" id="op3">
            <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.op3}'));</script>
            <span>Or without section items at all</span>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 4" id="op4" columns="1">
            <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.op4}')); </script>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <span style="text-align:left">Or still as 1 tag but left-aligned.</span>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:page>
```

[image]

**Edit to answer the comment**

*It is working if there is only one pageblocksectionitem inside the pageblocksection. I need three columns inside the pageblock section. When I add two more pageblocksectionitems the spacing comes back even if align left is there for all three*

That's not spacing, that's the `<script>` tag also occupying 1 cell.

[image]

See if you can move the script outside of the section (but you'll have to provide a [more detailed "path"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm) of ids.

```
<apex:page id="p">
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Option 4" id="op4" columns="3">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <span style="text-align:left">Content 1</span>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <span style="text-align:left">Content 2</span>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <span style="text-align:left">Content 3</span>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('img_{!$Component.p.pb.op4}'));</script>
</apex:page>
```

Or you could have a look at [`apex:panelBar, apex:panelBarItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_panelBarItem.htm) for "proper" accordion-like functionality without extra JS hacks and stuff breaking when the page structure changes?

Comment: I tried option 4. It is  working if there is only one pageblocksectionitem inside the pageblocksection. I need three columns inside the pageblock section. When I add two more pageblocksectionitems the spacing comes back even if align left is there for all three.